# How to auto resize height of month view in dhx scheduler?

Tags: dhtmlx-scheduler

Here is my code.

```html
<html>
<body style="height:100%">
<div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style="width:100%;height:100%">
...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I got full screen dhx scheduler container without scrollbar in right side.That's fine and very pretty.
But I added a div container to be needed so I got the container has cut the bottom side off.
Here is my updated code.

```html
<html>
<body style="height:100%">
<div>
...
</div>
<div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style="width:100%;height:100%">
...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get full month view container?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar situation. Adjust the height of the scheduler manually and it will be fixed. I have mine inside a bootstrap container so it automatically adjusts for me. But you can reduce the height to 50% and set the top div to 50% to make it work!